# Launching threads cause segmentation fault on pointer initialization

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, segmentation-fault

Why will this piece of code cause a segmentation fault on `*y = 20` only when two "empty" threads are launched?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int x = 10;
    int *y;
    *y = 20;

    std::thread t1([]{});
    std::thread t2([]{});

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you did not initialize ```y``` , so you are attempting to write ```20``` in some random memory

Comment: Threads (or their lack) has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your titles. There's a reason we keep editing them out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dereferencing an uninitialized (or null) pointer is undefined behavior.
Whatever happens in such a case is up to the compiler.

You probably meant to do something like:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int x = 10;
    int *y = &x;
    *y = 20;

    std::thread t1([]{});
    std::thread t2([]{});

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    return 0;
}
```

in which case it will work regardless of the threads being there or not.